# How can I make mySQL table rows selectable in an HTML form?

Tags: php

I have an html page in which all the data from an sql database is displayed in a table. I need to make the table act like a form in which the user selects specific rows within the table, which can then be submitted into another sql table.  Thus far I have linked the mySQL table to the html page via php.  Here is the very rudimentary code.

```
    <?php
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "student_login");
        if ($conn-> connect_error) 
        {
            die("Connection failed:". $conn-> connect_error);
        }
        
        $sql = "SELECT Course_Code, Course_Name, Program, Credits from courses";
        $result = $conn-> query($sql);
        
        if ($result-> num_rows > 0) 
            {
                while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc())
                {
                    echo "<tr><td>". $row["Course_Code"] ."</td><td>". $row["Course_Name"] ."</td><td>". $row["Program"] ."</td><td>". $row["Credits"] ."</td></tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "0 result";
            }
            
        $conn-> close();
     ?>
```

now the output looks as like this:[image]

Now I just need to make the displayed list act like a form in which user can select their courses and submit the selected courses.  Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: you can start off by using `<form>`  tags.  and processing them using php https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: What's your exact question here? About how to write a form? About how to process it? In which way is the `DESCRIBE` connected to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You want your html to look something like this:

```
<form method="post">
 <table>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="id-1"/></td>
      <td>Course 1</td>
       <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="id-2"/></td>
      <td>Course 2</td>
       <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- more rows -->
 </table>


<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Or since the backend is PHP, `<input type="checkbox" value="ID_HERE" name="ids[]">`, and it'll be automagically array-fied.